# Reading an ICS Calendar file in Android 7

Tags: calendar, google-calendar, 7.1-nougat, motorola-nexus-6

When I book a travel, the company sends me a reminder with one or more `ics` files that work fine with Microsoft Outlook.

I buy almost only from computer, because official Android app does not offer the same discounts: I mean, this specific rail company almost sells regular-price tickets via app, but if you browse their website from desktop computer you may be able to find discounted prices for the very same journey. Plus, there is no ticket synchronization with this specific vendor even if I use the same account on the website and application.

I can't use anymore `Local Sync for Android` ([R.I.P.](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cz.psencik.simple)), so I end up with a reminder email message into my Outlook/Gmail app with those `ics` files attached.

When I open the `ics` file with Android Calendar it won't import it. Also worth to note I don't use Gmail address. The Gmail *app* is configured with my IMAP mailbox to get the rail tickets.

Question: with vanilla Android 7, is there a trick to import an `ics` calendar file into Android Calendar? Didn't Google add support for standard `ics` files into their app? Is it possible **not** to install yet another app?

Comment: why don't you try [Blue Mail](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.bluemail.mail) app.

Comment: Thanks for pointing the app. In order to follow StackExchange rules, you must disclose your affiliation with the program if you are the author or work for them. Recommending an app can (and should be) posted as an answer with some indications/explanations of what the app does and how to fix the OP problem with the app, always by disclosing own affiliation